# Gson pattern - What is the point? Parsing complex dynamic data

Tags: java, android, json, design-patterns, gson

I'm working on a Android application that deals with a lot of incoming dynamic JSON data. I originally wrote my own methods for dealing with the data using the standard org.json packages. I was struggling with making it "feel clean" and it was generally pretty buggy.

After investigating solutions I've rebuilt most of my methods using Gson. I'm dealing with a lot of nested objects with more nested arrays and further nested objects.

I've got a top level container class which looks like

```
public class MovieContainer implements Serializable {

private List<Movie> movies;

public List<Movie> getMovies() {
    return movies;
   }
}
```

The movie class contains

```
public class Movie implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SerializedName("rating")
    private Rating ratings;

    @SerializedName("tmdb_id")
    private int tmdbID;

    @SerializedName("actor_roles")
    private Actor actors;

    // ...20 or so items and getters/setters removed for brevity
```

I've then got another class to deal with the Actors, which might have its own class for its own objects, likewise for the Ratings class and so on.

To parse my JSON I've currently got 12 different classes.

When I need to access something from a nested object my java ends up looking like

```
movieItem.getImages().getBackdrop().getURL()
```

Which doesn't really feel very clean for a start.

I've used a few custom Deserializer methods to deal with dynamic objects and I feel like I've just replicated my messy bloated code to solve this issue in the first place. I have added a large number of classes and complexity and I'm struggling to see what I gained from it.

Am I just using GSON completely wrong? have I missed the point all together? Is there some standardized patterns I should be using but just can't find examples of?

Any direction on how I should correctly be dealing with this would be much appreciated.

A snippit of input might look like https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5c5413c80bcbe7c3d25a (Its pretty long so won't post it here)

Answer (score 0):

Gson works on **Java Reflection**. Using Gson library you dont need yo deal with Mapping objects. The library does on its own.

For e.g. if you map an object you will first search if its present in the response object or not and then get its value. Say the count of object get increased to 1000 your code will also increase but not in case of Gosn. It will automatically Map objects from the response using Java Reflection.

I hope i made myself clear. What else, It is an official library offered by Google. :). You can rely on it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond but this doesn't really explain to me how I can implement it in a reasonable/usable fashion...

Comment: Okay, See you i suggest you use a single pojo class for all josn objects. Each time you need to refer the same class to Map objects and Gson will automatically parse the necessary objects and keep all extra json objects as null.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, so I store the nested objects simply in something like List<ObjectName> listObject? Rather than creating a seperate class and value for those objects?

Comment: Exactly, Create a wrapper class first and then hold all objects in a single pojo class. So you will end up making two classes to parse each json object.